# how to open simApplication about iOS

Tags: ios

iOS how to access `SIMApplication`, like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]];
```

Any Help?

Comment: You can't open the settings app on a specific page, you are only able to open your apps page.

Comment: Have you set `prefs` in URLTypes?

Comment: how to set prefs about sim application or how to open sim application

Comment: As mention above, you can open only settings and its sub root page not a simApplication...so for that you need to set `prefs`.

Comment: now i want to open a simApplication ,how  to do it.

Comment: or how to set prefs

Comment: Ok see my answer..!

Answer (score 0):

To open that URL which is given by you, you need to set `prefs` like below

Go to Project settings --> Info --> URL Types --> Add New URL Schemes

[image]

Then you can access your Url like,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i know what you say,but i want to open sim Application or go to SIM Application menu

Comment: i ' don't know url about Sim application

Comment: It is not possible to access the SIM Application in iOS. You can search for private headers to use in your project, but you won't get approved for release on the AppStore.